# trying to compare 2 string if statement

Tags: javascript, php, dom

I am trying to compare 2 strings, but there are not comparing as I would like. I am getting a value from a div and converting it to a string, when I find the typeof it is telling me is a string but still it is passing by the if statement.

When I write.document they both look the same.
Thanks

```
<div id="countries"><?php $geoplugin->locate(); echo"{$geoplugin->countryName}"?> </div> 

<script>
                 var country = document.getElementById("countries");
                 var count = country.innerHTML;
                 var newc = String(count);


                 if ( newc === "Ireland" ){
                    document.write("this is ireland");
                    alert("You are from Ireland");

                 }else{
                    document.write("You Live in " + newc);
                                    //alert(typeof newc);                  
                    //alert(newc);

                 }

                 </script>
```

Comment: `<?php $geoplugin->locate(); echo"{$geoplugin->countryName}"?>` should be `<?php $geoplugin->locate(); echo $geoplugin->countryName; ?>`, missing `;` and missing blankspace

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of `String(count)`, you should do `""+count` to [increase the speed of execution](http://jsperf.com/type-convertion).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your HTML it looks like you've got a trailing space after the `<?php ...>` instruction. So whatever is there, it won't exactly equal `"Ireland"`. Try using [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to remove any whitespace from the ends of your string.

```
var newc = String(count).trim();
```

Comment: Thanks p.s.w.g that was it white space somewhere.